# In-amp output lower than expected

Tags: resistors, switches, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm trying to create a circuit that can sense the state of a SPST switch in a series loop (constraints don't allow for the use of a DPST switch).  The idea is to expand this to work with more than just 1 switch in the loop, but for this example, I'm just testing with 1 switch to rule out variables.

I'm using an in-amp to measure the potential difference across a switch-resistor pair.  Circuit and important waveforms are as follows:

[image]

The blue waveform (V(n001)) is the node connected to IN+, the red waveform (V(n007)) is the node connected to IN-, and the green waveform (V(n004)) is the node connected to the output of the in-amp.

I'm using a spice model of the [AD8422](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8422.pdf) as the in-amp.  In the simulation, I'm turning on the switch (SW1) after 5ms elapse, shorting the IN+ and IN- terminals.

According to the datasheet, with the 1k resistor connected across RG- and RG+, I currently have the differential gain set to ~500.  With a potential difference of 3V across the inputs of the in-amp, I would expect this to rail the output of the amplifier, but the results show the output is slightly higher than 1V.  I am wondering why this is the case.  Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are correct, that was a typo.  Edited and updated post.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying ~9 V to IN+, but only using +5 V supply. That's going to cause problems. Try changing V7 to a 5 V supply.

The input voltage operating range spec is -Vs + 1.2 V to Vs - 1.2 V, so really you should make sure the input voltages are between 1.2 and 3.8 V.

Comment: That worked like a charm! I ended up connecting +Vs to +12V - but same idea. Thank you.